# symfony2 my own event

Tags: events, symfony, dispatcher

I made the authorization and authentication via facebook like here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html
and it works

Now I want to make my own event, this event will do something when the user authenticates using facebook. For example-will redirect the user to the home page.
I did it like this
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html

So I have this class
http://pastebin.com/2FTndtL4

I do not know how to implement it, what am I supposed to pass as an argument to the constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event object is just some kind of state/data storage. It keeps data that can be useful for dispatching some kind of events via Subscribers and/or Listeners. So, for example, if you wanna pass facebook id to your Listener(s) - Event is the right way of storing it. Also event is the return value of dispatcher. If you want to return some data from your Listener/Subscriber - you can also store it in Event object.

Comment: parameter of constructor will be Facebook User Token ?

Comment: it can be Facebook User Token if you wanna use it in your listeners

Comment: and so what? Facebook User?

Comment: Yes, i think it'll be useful

Answer (score 2):

It's really simple. Symfony 2 event system is powerful, and service tags will do the job.

1. Inject the dispatcher into the class where you want to fire the event. The service id is `event_dispatcher`;
2. Fire the event with `$this->dispatcher->dispatch('facebook.post_auth', new FilterFacebookEvent($args))` when needed;
3. Make a service that implements `EventSubscriberInterface`, defining a static `getSubscribedEvents()` method. Of course you want to listen to `facebook.post_auth` event.

So your static method will look like:

```php
static public function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        'facebook.post_auth' => 'onPostAuthentication'
    );
}

public function onPostAuthentication(FilterFacebookEvent $event)
{
    // Do something, get the event args, etc
}
```

Finally register this service as a subscriber for the dispatcher: give it a tag (eg. `facebook.event_subscriber`), then make a `RegisterFacebookEventsSubscribersPass` (see [this tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/dependency_injection/tags.html)). You compiler pass should retrieve all tagged services and inside the loop should call:

```php
$dispatcher  = $container->getDefinition('event_dispatcher');
$subscribers = $container->findTaggedServiceIds('facebook.event_subscriber');

foreach($subscribers as $id => $attributes) {
    $definition->addMethodCall('addSubscriber', array(new Reference($id)));
}
```

This way you can quick make a subscriber (for logging, for example) simply tagging your service.